# Los dados siempre son los mismos

Tags: java

Hola sigo por mi cuenta un curso de Java y estoy haciendo una practica que ha puesto al final del ultimo video que he visto 
y lo tengo casi hecho, pero deberia de generarme 3 numeros distintos para cada dado y siempre me hace el mismo.

```
public class Tres_Dados_Suma_Total {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dado[] = new int [3];
        int num_Aleatorio = (int) (Math.random()*6) + 1;
        int suma = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            dado[i] = num_Aleatorio;
            System.out.println("El dado " + (i + 1) + " es: " + dado[i]);
            suma = suma+dado[i];
        }
        System.out.print("La suma de los tres dados es: " + suma);
    }
}
```

¿Porqué es? ayuda por favor.

Comment: Debes de añadir la variable de aleatorio dentro del bucle

Answer (score 12, accepted):

!Buenas!

Estas declarando una variable al principio del programa, fuera del bucle `for`, llamada `num_Aleatorio`. En esta variable, efectivamente, estas almacenando un numero aleatorio. Pero en ningún momento se vuelve a generar ningún numero nuevo para sobrescribir el valor de la variable `num_Aleatorio`.

Para que tu programa funcione debes de incluir el numero aleatorio **dentro** del bucle `for` para que cada *vuelta del bucle* genere un numero aleatorio nuevo y lo almacene en, este caso, la variable `num_Aleatorio`.

Aunque veo una pequeña mejora; que seria eliminar dicha variable y almacenar directamente el valor aleatorio en `dado`, quedando así el programa:

```
public class Tres_Dados_Suma_Total {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int dado[] = new int [3];
        int suma=0;

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            dado[i] = (int) (Math.random()*6)+1;
            System.out.println("El dado " + (i+1) + " es: " + dado[i]);
            suma= suma+dado[i];
        }

        System.out.print("La suma de los tres dados es: " + suma);

    }

}
```

Espero que te ayude a entender mejor :)

Comment: aaah vale ahora entiendo